Kubernetes sometime fails to update pod-deletion-cost
we have a NodeJS service that runs jobs using bull, we are scaling using Keda's Redis plugin.
this works great the problem is that when Kubernetes scales down he can kills pods that are running heavy jobs. to solve the issue we decided to manage the pod-deletion-cost annotation on the pod. so each job gets a cost and when a job starts running we increase the total cost of the pod and decrease it back when the job is finished.
all of that works great and even the pod-deletion-cost get updated. the problem is that about 70% of the pod-deletion-cost updates gets the following error:
Pod "redacted" is invalid: spec: Forbidden: pod updates may not change fields other than `spec.containers[*].image`,`spec.initContainers[*].image`,`spec.activeDeadlineSeconds`,`spec.tolerations` (only additions to existing tolerations),`spec.terminationGracePeriodSeconds` (allow it to be set to 1 if it was previously negative)
  core.PodSpec{
    Volumes:        {redacted...},
    InitContainers: nil,
    Containers: []core.Container{
        {
            ... // 6 identical fields
            EnvFrom: nil,
            Env:     {redacted...},
            Resources: core.ResourceRequirements{
                Limits: {s"memory": {i: {...}, Format: "BinarySI"}},
                Requests: core.ResourceList{
-                   s"cpu":    {i: resource.int64Amount{value: 77, scale: -3}, s: "77m", Format: "DecimalSI"},
+                   s"cpu":    {i: resource.int64Amount{value: 73, scale: -3}, s: "73m", Format: "DecimalSI"},
                    s"memory": {i: {...}, s: "935Mi", Format: "BinarySI"},
                },
                Claims: nil,
            },
            ResizePolicy:  nil,
            RestartPolicy: nil,
            ... // 13 identical fields
        },
    },
    EphemeralContainers: nil,
    RestartPolicy:       "Always",
    ... // 28 identical fields
  }

with error code 422
not sure why because the next time we try to update it can work and than it can not work at all for like an hour

From the error message it seems that somehow you are trying to change the cpu specifications of the pod from 77 to 73 instead of changing the pod-deletion-cost.
-s"cpu":    {i: resource.int64Amount{value: 77, scale: -3}, s: "77m", Format: "DecimalSI"}, +s"cpu":    {i: resource.int64Amount{value: 73, scale: -3}, s: "73m", Format: "DecimalSI"},
These values are static and cannot be changed at runtime.
Also from the official documentation it is suggested to use pod-deletion-cost when your application is controlling the scaling and not Keda because a race condition can happen when you are trying to update the pod-deletion-cost of a pod which is already evicted by Keda.
Also, regarding the original problem you are facing where the pods that are running heavy jobs are deleted, I will suggest using jobs instead of deployment.
As an alternate to scaling event-driven code as deployments you can also run and scale your code as Kubernetes Jobs. The primary reason to consider this option is to handle processing long-running executions. Rather than processing multiple events within a deployment, for each detected event a single Kubernetes Job is scheduled. That job will initialize, pull a single event from the message source, and process to completion and terminate.
This will ensure that no pod that is running the job is terminated in between.
More on this in this doc.

thank you very much, but this is weird because im calling patch pod of the client.
i did not provide new cpu value so why would it do that?

i would even add when this happens even calling kubectl annotate causes the same issue
